# Class "View controller" has no initializers

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

I got an "Class "View controller" has no initializers" error.

I tried to initialize all variables but the error keeps appearing.

Hear is the code:

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Screen: UILabel!
    var primerNum = Float()
    var segundoNum = Float()
    var result = Float()
    var operat = ""
    var isTypingNumber = false
    var num: Int?
    var coma: Int?

    @IBAction func num(sender: AnyObject) {
     var num = sender.currentTitle
        if isTypingNumber == true {
            Screen.text = Screen.text! + num!!
        } else {
            Screen.text = num
        }
        isTypingNumber = true
    }

    @IBAction func coma(sender: AnyObject) {
        var coma = sender.currentTitle
        Screen.text = Screen.text! + coma!!
    }

    @IBAction func operat(sender: AnyObject) {
        operat = sender.currentTitle!!
        primerNum = (Screen.text! as NSString).floatValue

    }

    @IBAction func igual(sender: AnyObject) {
        segundoNum = (Screen.text! as NSString).floatValue
        if operat == "+" {
            result = primerNum + segundoNum
        } else if operat == "-" {
            result = primerNum - segundoNum
        } else if operat == "x" {
            result = primerNum * segundoNum
        } else if operat == "/" {
            result = primerNum / segundoNum
        } else if operat == "%" {
            result = (primerNum * segundoNum) / 100
        }
        Screen.text = "\(result)"
    }

    @IBAction func clear(sender: AnyObject) {
        primerNum = 0
        segundoNum = 0
        result = 0
        Screen.text = "\(result)"
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

That looks correct, and also compiles fine for me locally.  Did you try Cleaning and rebuilding (command-shift-K, then command-b)?  Alternatively, restart Xcode.

Comment: I would also recommend to update xcode if problem persists after clean and restart.